# How do you get prometheus metrics from QuestDB

Tags: questdb

I see that there's support for prometheus metrics added to QuestDB in https://github.com/questdb/questdb/pull/905

How do I get metrics or gauges out of QuestDB into prom? If I search for metrics [on the configuration page](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/#telemetry) it shows something for telemetry which I'm guessing is not the same endpoint or function.

Any help here would be a plus as it would be really useful to have DB metrics for this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 6.0.4, a `/metrics` endpoint serves basic Prometheus metrics on port `9003`:

There are details here: https://questdb.io/blog/2021/07/16/release-6-0-4/#prometheus-metrics

In your prometheus config, point it towards port 9003 of a QuestDB instance:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: "questdb"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "questdb"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["127.0.0.1:9003"]
```